# Configuration of general workflow with generic interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.5

We recently stumbled across a problem in our data collection program. We use generic interfaces to have a general workflow that's easily customizable for different data inputs via concrete implementations in a config. A recent fix for a missing data bug is looking in general like the following:

```
[TestFixture]
internal class GenericsTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Config()
    {
        new Collector(new Search());
    }
    internal class Collector
    {
        public Collector(Clues<Where, What> foo)
        {

        }
    }
    internal interface Clues<T, P>
    {

    }
    internal class Search : Clues<Where, Item>
    {

    }
    internal class Where
    {

    }
    internal class Item : What
    {

    }

    internal interface What
    {

    }

}
```

The Config is initializing a specific Collector with a specific Search. The Collector itself is only expecting a generic interface with a concrete class Where and interface What as parameters. 
The Search class should satisfy these expectations by implementing the generic Clues interface with the Where class and the Item class which itself implements the What interface.
Instead the initialization of Search fails because it can't make the connection between the specific implementations and the general expectation.

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnitTest.GenericsTest.GenericsTest.Search' to 'UnitTest.GenericsTest.GenericsTest.Clues<UnitTest.GenericsTest.GenericsTest.Where, UnitTest.GenericsTest.GenericsTest.What>'
```

We tried casting to the required types, but it only shifted the error to runtime.

The general concept is, that the workflow stays as generic as possible and the config takes care of all specific requirements. The concrete methods needed are supposed to be introduced in the item class and hidden behind the interface to avoid unnecessary cluttering.

Is there a specific way to write such an implementation in C#?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I removed the tags from your question's title. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to change the definition of `Clues` 
and use [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Covariance:
>   Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified

```
internal interface Clues<T, out P>
```

---

**Edit**

If you can't change the interface, then maybe you can change the `Collector` class to use generics with constraints instead:

```
internal class Collector<TWhere,TWhat> where TWhere:Where where TWhat:What
{
    public Collector(Clues<TWhere, TWhat> foo)
    {

    }
}
```

Then you must specify exactly the types your'e going to use:

```
public void Config()
{
    new Collector<Where,Item>(new Search());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
We were fiddling around with covariance and while it works for the simple example above, it breaks some levels lower for us.
The Clues interface itself contains a method which uses another interface of generic type <P>. This in turn needs to be invariant then, but cant be, because the interface has a Get and Set method for type <P>.

Comment: Our current workaround uses the interface instead of the implementation and casts to the appropriate type when the Get method is called.

Comment: @Moldavis i've edited the answer with another suggestion - hope it'll help

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this solution throws the same error as the original problem.

Comment: What error it throws? it works for me. Are you sure you've copied the same as i posted?